# How can I reproduce custom text in "designed format" on console using dotnet core console application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, console, console-application

This might sound quite silly, but I want to know how can I display some custom text on console; like when I do "ng --version"?

[image]

I also would appreciate if you could let me know "what is it called" and how can I reproduce this using ASP.net Core Console Application.

I'm unable to search it since I don't know what it is called.. Silly me. :-)

Comment: Have you heard of Console.WriteLine? It's probably just a string like space space space hyphen space space space ... etc

Comment: The keyword is ASCII Art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google search returned me to this url ==> https://github.com/drewnoakes/figgle

Works like a charm with ASP.net Core 3.1 for me.